# Cookie can't be deleted

Tags: php, cookies

I cannot delete an existing cookie which is set with PHP. I'm sure that it is set with PHP because, if i clear my cookies + disable JS it is still appending.

I can see this cookie appended for example: www.domain.com and the path to the cookie seems to be "/". I have tryed a LOT method described here but nothing works... the cookie is just there. Another interesting thing is that i can even get + echo the value of the cookie.  It is not a session cookie.

My need is only to find a way to delete this cookie :/

Comment: Can you show the code, or live example?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you delete a cookie, you set the cookie again, but with a `expires` value somewhere in the past. Have you done this?

Comment: Ye... I have tryed what i saw here, basically everything :(

Comment: So, If there is such a script that can delete ALL cookies and it is working 100% anythime it will be great...

Comment: You could fetch all values in your $_COOKIE array and set a new cookie with expiration date on them in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set empty cookie value and expired time 0?

Answer (score 0):

Since you typing also in cyrillic, check if the cookie name if written with latin symbols or is mixed with cyrillic/latin by mistake (happened to me - you know that some chars are looking absolutely the same).
Or you may have trailing space/new line at the end in some of your include files that force sending the output. Put ob_start() in the very beginning of your bootstrap php file.